# Python how to convert capnproto to json?

Tags: python, json, capnproto

I have some legacy with capnp binary data in Postgress database, i want to convert it to jsonb

Are there any ready solutions in python to convert data from capnp to json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `pycapnp` [library](https://github.com/capnproto/pycapnp).

First i need to load from binary to python object (with use of capnp chema).
Then I can call `.to_dict()` on my capnp object.